# Dealing with multiple-inherited constructors in Moose

Tags: perl, oop, moose, mop, cgiapp

Greetings,

I'm learning [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/) and I'm trying to write a [CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI-Application/) subclass with Moose, which is made difficult by the fact that CGI-App is not based on Moose.

In my other CGI-App subclasses, I like to have a parent class with a `setup` method that looks at the child class's symbol table and automatically sets up the runmodes. I figure I can use Moose's metaclass facilities to achieve the same thing in a cleaner way. So here is what I have in my parent class:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class MyApp::CGI 
extends Moose::Object
extends CGI::Application { 

    method setup { 
        $self->start_mode( 'main' );

        my @methods = map { $_->name } $self->meta->get_all_methods;

        $self->run_modes( map  { /^rm_(.+)$/  => $_ }
                          grep { /^rm_/ }
                          @methods
                        );
    }

}
```

...and in my child class:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class MyApp::CGI::Login 
extends MyApp::CGI { 
    method rm_main { 
        return "it works";
    }
}
```

I realized that the reason my runmodes were not getting setup properly is because `setup` is called by the CGI-App constructor, and `Moose::Object` is sticking its own constructor in my class. I tried to solve this with a method modifier:

```
around new { 
    $self = $orig->( @_ );
    $self->CGI::Application::new( @_ );
}
```

This gives me

```
Can't call method "BUILDARGS" on unblessed reference at ...Moose/Object.pm line 21.
```

I have a feeling, however, that I'm going about this in completely the wrong way, and Moose has a much better facility for achieving what I want, which I have not as yet discovered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you already looked at [Moose::Cookbook::Basics::DateTime_ExtendingNonMooseParent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Cookbook::Basics::DateTime_ExtendingNonMooseParent) and [MooseX::NonMoose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::NonMoose)?

**Update:** I am not very familiar with Moose and assorted techniques. I was not able to get the modules to compile using `MooseX::Declare` and `MooseX::NonMoose` together. However, here is something that seems to work:

**Application Base Class**

```
package My::App;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
extends 'CGI::Application';

sub setup {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->start_mode( 'main' );

    $self->run_modes(
        map { $_ = $_->name;
              /^rm_ (?<rm>.+) $/x ? ( $+{rm} => $_ ) : ()
        } $self->meta->get_all_methods
    );
}

"My::App"
```

**Derived Class**

```
package My::Login;
use Moose;
extends 'My::App';

sub rm_main { 'it works!' }

"My::Login"
```

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# For testing on the command line
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use lib $Bin;

use My::Login;

my $app = My::Login->new;

$app->run;
```

**Output**

```
C:\Temp\f> t
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

it works!
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to get MooseX::NonMoose to work properly, but I was able to get my base class to inherit from CGI-App properly with the recipe from the Cookbook.

Comment: @friedo Thanks for accepting my answer. I am thinking there must be a way to get `MooseX::Declare` to play nice with `MooseX::NonMoose` but this I could not figure it out.