# Turning off inline constructors with MooseX::Declare

Tags: perl, oop, moose, mop

Greetings,

As a followup to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057661/dealing-with-multiple-inherited-constructors-in-moose) about Moose, I've now run into a new problem. I've got a Moose class which uses [Recipe 12](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose-0.85/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Basics/Recipe11.pod) in order to extend a non-Moose parent class. Here it is:

```
package MyApp::CGI;

### TODO: make this work with MooseX::Declare?

use Moose;
extends 'CGI::Application';

sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    my $obj = $class->SUPER::new( @_ );
    return $class->meta->new_object( __INSTANCE__ => $obj, @_ );
}

sub setup {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->start_mode( 'main' );

    my @methods = map { $_->name } $self->meta->get_all_methods;

    $self->run_modes( map  { /^rm_(.+)$/  => $_ }
                      grep { /^rm_/ }
                      @methods
                    );        
}
```

This works great. I also have a subclass of this class which uses `MooseX::Declare`. However, because I am now overriding the default Moose constructor, my subclass emits this warning:

```
Not inlining 'new' for MyApp::CGI::Login since it is not inheriting the default Moose::Object::new
If you are certain you don't need to inline your constructor, specify inline_constructor => 0 in your call to MyApp::CGI::Login->meta->make_immutable
```

Since `MooseX::Declare` calls `make_immutable` automatically behind the scenes, I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to turn on the `inline_constructor => 0` parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to some folks on IRC I was able to crack this one. Declaring the class `mutable` was sufficient to turn off the `auto_make_immutable` flag in `MooseX::Declare`, so I could then do it manually. (Of course this also works with a non-MX::Declare class.)

Revised version:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class MyApp::CGI extends CGI::Application is mutable { 

    around new { 
        my $obj = $self->SUPER::new( @_ );
        return $self->meta->new_object( __INSTANCE__ => $obj, @_ );
    }

    method setup {
        $self->start_mode( 'main' );

        my @methods = map { $_->name } $self->meta->get_all_methods;

        $self->run_modes( map  { /^rm_(.+)$/  => $_ }
                          grep { /^rm_/ }
                          @methods
                        );
    }

    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable( inline_constructor => 0 );
 }
```